# unset($_SESSION['cart'])

Tags: php

Господа, помогите, пожалуйста, не работает:

```
<?
function clear() {
$_SESSION['cart'] = array();
unset($_SESSION['cart']);
}
?>
<? 
echo "<input type=button value='Очистить' onclick=clear()>";
?>
```

Answer (score 5):

Если вы решили вызвать функцию php из javascript, то точно не сработает. Лучше так:

```
<a href="?clear">Очистить</a> <- главное - передать в $_GET переменную clear
...
<?
if(isset($_GET['clear'])){
    unset($_SESSION['cart']);
}
?>
```

Comment: нет не ява

Comment: Что - не ява?

Comment: DiTso вы явно ошибаетесь. @ling описал вам абсолютно работающий способ. В отличие от вашего. 
<? function clear() {..}?> - вы описали функцию в php
...onclick=clear()>"; - вы вызываете функцию clear из javascript